# Running old mono version

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I am trying to install old mono version (2.6.7) on Ubuntu 14.10 I tried to change repo at

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

on

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshot/2.6.7 main
```

and it hadn't helped. Is there exist other way.

Comment: Can you expand on "*it hadn't helped*"? It's hard to help with limited information.

Comment: it hadn't helped means that even with such a fix new mono version has installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Mono repository only has packages for Mono versions 3.8 and later (see [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases) for how to access them).

Mono 2.6.7 is quite old by now so I think your best bet is to compile [from sources](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/).

Comment: Thank you I will try such a way